# Split the Table of Contents in two pages

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking

Let's say I'm writing a document with 6 chapters. I want to force the table of contents to be split between two pages. The first page would list the first 4 chapters, the second page would list the last 2 chapters.

How can I do that?

If it matters, assume the document class is report.

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: @Seamus: Well, the example above is a simplified version. I want to have all chapters listed on the first page, and all appendixes listed on the second. The reason is that currently the ToC is already longer than a single page, so I think it will look nicer if I split it nicely.

Comment: @Seamus: It is possible that a pagebreak in the ToC will occur after the first section of a chapter. This is akin to orphans in the main text, and some people may want to avoid it.

Comment: adding page breaks to a toc is best left for last minute fine tuning, when you know exactly where the "natural" breaks have occurred.  it's not at all uncommon.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Within the body text, right before the fifth chapter, you could add a line break to the `.toc` file, for example:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}
```

Comment: But that must be done again after every compile cycle, right?

Comment: @Matthias No, just once. This line goes into the document, not into the .toc file. The latter would require it, that's right.

Comment: Works in Lyx as well when placed within a TeX code block.

Comment: `\pagebreak` would be better.