# Pagebreak within the List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking

How can I have a page break manually inserted into the list of figures (`\listoffigures`)? I need a page break after a certain line/image-caption.

Consider MWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
\newpage
%%------------List of Figures----------------------
\listoffigures{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

\chapter{someCH}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
   \centering
      \includegraphics[height=8cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{bb}
\end{figure}

\part*{Test}
\markboth{}{}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
   \centering
      \includegraphics[height=8cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{name}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
   \centering
      \includegraphics[height=8cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{bbb}
\end{figure}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\pagebreak}
\appendix
\chapter{chapt}\label{a.b}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
   \centering
      \includegraphics[height=8cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{name}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello! Maybe this could serve as a starting point? But I didn’t try this on figures or tables yet https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6489/split-the-table-of-contents-in-two-pages

Comment: `\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\newpage}` After the figure where the pagebrak shoul be

Comment: Do this when you're sure you won't make any other change and clearly mark the code in order to be able to find it: between two paragraphs before the figure you want in the next page add `\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\pagebreak}`.

Comment: So, now you got the same answer about three times ;)

Comment: @JasperHabicht But `\pagebreak` is better than `\newpage`, actually, because if `\flushbottom` is in force LaTeX will fill the page rather than truncate it.

Comment: @egreg why all this preventions?... And it does not work as expected.. As it inserts a pagebreak few figures before I put the line

Comment: @Jan it will work if used at the correct place but you have given no indication of your code so it is hard to help by saying what is wrong with your input.

Comment: see edit.. i want the appendix-figures on a new page... But maybe I will consider a seperate list of figures for the appendix (And will accept corresponding answers).. Nonetheless it would be good to know whats wrong there..

Comment: see how much easier it is to answer given a test file:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add the extra line with the page break after the pages on to which the other floats had floated (or add it within the float) placing it in the first appendix is simplest here

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
\newpage
%%------------List of Figures----------------------
\listoffigures{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

\chapter{someCH}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
   \centering
      \includegraphics[height=8cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{bb}
\end{figure}

\part*{Test}
\markboth{}{}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
   \centering
      \includegraphics[height=8cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{name}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
   \centering
      \includegraphics[height=8cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{bbb}
\end{figure}



\appendix
\chapter{chapt}\label{a.b}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\pagebreak}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
   \centering
      \includegraphics[height=8cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{name}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```